# BottomBar View take space from screen even it is not visible on IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

we have a NavigationContainer that contain both the pages and the bottom bar, the bottom bar is visible only on some page (we control that using hook that listen to screenListeners when get changed), the issue is when we navigate to a page that doesn't have a bottom bar, the bottom bar still take space (the same height when it is visible) from the screen even it is not visible, is there a way to solve that?

[NavigationContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECHjG.png)

or how can we listen to navigation.navigate so we can hide the bottom bar from the tree before the navigation happen?